# JQuery resizable with three divs does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used Jquery resizable for one of my projects. I want three divs side by side with two separators and resize each one accordingly. I was able to resize the first two divs without an issue. However I can't get to work the third one.

and one more issue that I have is when you move the splitter one it also moves the last-splitter and div.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4xnq8gd/6/)

```js
 $(".panel-left").resizable({
   handleSelector: ".splitter",
   resizeHeight: false
 });
 
  $(".panel-right").resizable({
   handleSelector: ".splitter-right",
   resizeHeight: false
 });
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.page-container {
  margin: 20px;
}

/* horizontal panel*/

.panel-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* avoid browser level touch actions */
  xtouch-action: none;
}

.panel-left {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  /* only manually resize */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 150px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #838383;
  color: white;
}

.splitter {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 18px;
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/assets/vsizegrip.png) center center no-repeat #535353;
  min-height: 200px;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.splitter-right {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 18px;
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/assets/vsizegrip.png) center center no-repeat #535353;
  min-height: 200px;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.panel-center {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /* resizable */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}

.panel-right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /* resizable */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/src/jquery-resizable.js"></script>

<div class="page-container">
  <div class="panel-container">

    <div class="panel-left">
      left panel
    </div>

    <div class="splitter">
    </div>

    <div class="panel-center">
      center panel
    </div>
    
    <div class="splitter-right">
    </div>
    
    <div class="panel-right">
      center panel
    </div>


  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A correct answer for the horizontal three panels consists of

1. resizing **panel-center** instead of panel-right
2. setting it's **flex-shrink to 0**

```js
    $(".panel-left").resizable({
        handleSelector: ".splitter",
        resizeHeight: false
    });
 
    $(".panel-center").resizable({
        handleSelector: ".splitter-right",
        resizeHeight: false
    });
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.page-container {
  margin: 20px;
}



/* horizontal panel*/

.panel-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* avoid browser level touch actions */
  xtouch-action: none;
}

.panel-left {
  flex: 0 0 auto;  /* only manually resize */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 150px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #838383;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.splitter,
.splitter-right {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 18px;
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/assets/vsizegrip.png) center center no-repeat #535353;
  min-height: 200px;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.panel-center{
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #eee;
  color: #000;
}

.panel-right {
  flex: 0 0 auto;  /* only manually resize */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #838383;
  color: #ffffff;
}  
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Split Panels - jquery-resizable</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body style="">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/src/jquery-resizable.js"></script>
    <div class="page-container">

        <div class="panel-container">

            <div class="panel-left">
                left panel
            </div>

            <div class="splitter"></div>

            <div class="panel-center">
                center panel
            </div>

            <div class="splitter-right"></div>

            <div class="panel-right">
                right panel
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is better than the other answer, but you can't move `splitter-right` left of its initial position.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the working code:

```js
 $(".panel-left").resizable({
   handleSelector: ".splitter",
   resizeHeight: false
 });
 
  $(".panel-right").resizable({
   handleSelector: ".splitter-right",
   resizeHeight: false
 });
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.page-container {
  margin: 20px;
}

/* horizontal panel*/

.panel-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* avoid browser level touch actions */
  xtouch-action: none;
}

.panel-left {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  /* only manually resize */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #838383;
  color: white;
}

.splitter {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 5%;
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/assets/vsizegrip.png) center center no-repeat #535353;
  min-height: 200px;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.splitter-right {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 5%;
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/assets/vsizegrip.png) center center no-repeat #535353;
  min-height: 200px;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.panel-center {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /* resizable */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}

.panel-right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /* resizable */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/src/jquery-resizable.js"></script>

<div class="page-container">
  <div class="panel-container">

    <div class="panel-left">
      left panel
    </div>

    <div class="splitter">
    </div>

    <div class="panel-center">
      center panel
    </div>
    
    <div class="splitter-right">
    </div>
    
    <div class="panel-right">
      right panel
    </div>


  </div>


</div>
```

You Errors :

you gave `left-panel` width static and after that you gave it `min-width`, it was over-ridding the `width` attribute and after that you gave `width:100%` to both `center` and `right` , using display flex the total width that page was using as

100% + 100% + 300px + 18px + 18px (your splitter width)

Comment: Panels are working fine now however the right panel has an abnormal behaviour.

Comment: please elaborate it more precisely, the abnormal behaviour

Comment: If you move the right panel left, the div move the other way and vice versa.